# Read and show the content of DOC & DOCX file in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

Suppose user will upload doc or docx file through our asp.net web UI and after then we want to show the content of that doc file in our web page. So please tell me which library I need to use in my asp.net web project for reading the content of doc file and convert to html and then save the html to database. 
So I stuck that how to read and convert to html the doc file content. is there any good libarary for this.

Comment: why you people will not check the older answers given for a similar type of questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a .docx to html using asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113/how-do-i-convert-a-docx-to-html-using-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered perfectly in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55113/108847)