# How to get table dimension using mammoth?

Tags: node.js

I am using Mammoth to convert docx to html.

I am trying to convert html.  But table is converting without formatting.   How to get table with formatting.

If this is not possible, any alternate way to do this?

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from the mammoth docs - "Tables. The formatting of the table itself, such as borders, is currently ignored, but the formatting of the text is treated the same as in the rest of the document."

Comment: @Robbie: Any idea to get width and height of the table....

Comment: sorry, i've never used Mammoth before and am not very familiar with the docx format. FYI, the docs for mammoth are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth

Comment: @Vanarajan regardless of your issue, have you been able to deploy your app? I could not achieve it with dotnet-mammoth, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885962/converting-docx-to-html-with-dotnet-mammoth-fails-at-deploy-server)

Comment: @zed: sorry.  I didnot use dotnet.  I am using node.js application.